# Wordpress add_rewrite_rule gives 404

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, permalinks

I want to change the permalink structure for specific custom post type.i.e

```
http://test.com/brand/calvin-klien?mtype=tab2
                     ^this is dynamic
```

To

```
http://test.com/brand/calvin-klien/mtype/tab2
                      ^this is dynamic
```

Here is a piece of code I tried.

**Registering add_rewrite_tag**

```
function custom_rewrite_tag() {
        add_rewrite_tag('%mtype%', '([a-z0-9\-]+)');
    }
    add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_tag', 10, 0);

add_action('init', 'wpse50530_journal_archive_rewrite', 10, 0);
```

**Code1**

```
function wpse50530_journal_archive_rewrite(){

   add_rewrite_rule('brand/([a-z0-9\-]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)/$','index.php?name=$matches[1]/?mtype=$matches[2]','top');
}
```

**Code2**

```
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'work_list');
function work_list($wp_rewrite) {
    $newrules = array();
    $newrules['brand/([a-z0-9\-]+)/([a-z0-9\-]+)/$'] = 'index.php?name=$matches[1]&mtype=$matches[2]';
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $newrules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
```

I have tried both above `codes`, `flushed permalinks` but still a `404`. I dont know why it is creating **$matches** in htaccess as htacces doesnt know WHAT IS **$matches**

Also I have tried [monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/) which is showing the correct matched result for my permalink but still word press showing `404`. See attached screenshots for Code1 & Code2

[image: Code1![][1]][image: Code2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code should help

```
add_action( 'init', 'so_27487849' );

function so_27487849() {

    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^brand/([^/]*)/mtype/([^/]*)/?',
        'index.php?name=$matches[1]&mtype=$matches[2]',
        'top');

}
```

Flush your permalinks and it should work.

Comment: Thanks Anand I have done some changes but your answer was a starter for me :)

Comment: Can you please help me in this = I need 404 on putting wrong url. Correct is `brand/calvin-klein/tab1/watches1/` Wrong is `brand/calvin-klein/tab12231231/watches1/` but it still gives me the same error rather than a 404 page

Comment: 404 occurs when a page or post is not found, `tab12231231` is query variable, so you'll have to handle it inside your CPT code, check if its a valid `mtype` and if it isn't redirect to a different page or show an error message. You can manually raise a 404 , see the following thread on raising a 404 manually : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/91900/how-to-force-a-404-on-wordpress  .  And thanks for fixing the typo :)

Answer (score 0):

I will continue Anand's code for some further changes. It was redirecting on `name=$matches[1]` and I need to stay at the same URL I hit, for this it must include the custom post type name.

```
add_action( 'init', 'so_27487849' );
function so_27487849() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^brand/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?','index.php?brand=$matches[1]&mtype=$matches[2]','top');
                                                             ^--this
}
```

I got the Pretty URL... Yaaay!!!
**BUT** `URL` doesn't contain `query string(i.e: mtype=tab1)` and the rest of my code is useless, so we can achieve this by doing `get_query_var('mtype')` and I got the same value which was working in `$_REQUEST['mtype']` and my code worked like a charm.

Also I deactivated the [monkeyman pluggin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone has the same problem and checks out this page.

In the permalink settings page, check how the permalink structure is configured. The most common is to enter `/%postname%/` in the custom structure field to let the rewrite_rules work properly.

Answer (score -2):

before or after the call the function add_rewrite.. insert this code status_header(200);